# What is a formal alternative for being "on the same page"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, formal-language

I am working on a project where there are a number of different stakeholders (people funding the project, supervisor, secondary researchers, etc.).

One of the things I do is document all my main research activities and provide these summary reports to all the stakeholders every week. These reports do two things: update everyone on what I and my supervisor have been working on, and ensure that all stakeholders are **on the same page** regarding the direction of the research work. So for example, they will all confirm whether or not they feel the latest task and the planned tasks for the upcoming week are steps in the right direction.

I am looking for a formal way to express the second purpose: "ensure that all stakeholders are **on the same page**".

I have looked for a formal alternative for "on the same page", but found nothing.

I have tried the following:

> These reports also ensure that all stakeholders are well-informed about the current status of the project and that they agree on the priorities.

But there has to be a better way to express being on the same page in a more, much more, formal way.

Comment: Why not just say "all stakeholders agree on the direction..."? The definition of "on the same page" is basically "in agreement" or "have the same understanding or knowledge".

Comment: *Concur* is a very close substitute for *are on the same page.*  *The reports ensure all stakeholders **concur** on/regarding the direction of the research.*

Comment: @ColleenV Maybe you can turn that comment into an answer? It would be helpful.

Comment: @AIQ I was asking for clarification on why you didn't choose to use the obvious (to me) word, not really suggesting an answer.

Comment: @Oh I see. My bad. Well, I didn't go with "ensuring that all stakeholders agree on the direction of the research work" because it could be misleading. "Direction of the research work" sounds a bit too broad - as if they didn't agree on the research topic/question. What they had to agree on were more like the micro steps. Not sure if that makes sense ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would not hesitate, even a second, to use "on the same page" in a formal context. It does not carry any informal connotations, it's widely understood (I used it once translated literally into my native language (Dutch) and nobody objected) and sees wide usage in government publications ([1](https://cleancities.energy.gov/technical-assistance/workplace-charging/), [2](https://www.army.mil/article/232263/)).

On the other hand, you've already provided a good 'direct' example "agree on the priorities", so if you're more comfortable with it, why not use that?

Comment: Glor, would you use it in a resume/CV?

Comment: @AIQ In theory it's fine for a resume, but in most contexts I'd probably say it's too verbose and you should rephrase. On a resume I usually try to express things in as few words as possible, without sacrificing clarity or grammar, to provide a very focused and succinct description of what I did and achieved. But others may disagree on that.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I know, it's really hard to find that balance. For me, it's always a struggle to be able to express the details in as few words as possible. But will try, thanks!

Comment: Yes, that last paragraph. "On the same page" is a vague way of saying we agree on what's been decided and what's to be decided at this meeting. So skip to the chase and say that stuff -- "we previously agreed the mascot will be a shark, this meeting will decide what type and artistic style it will be". That needs to be said, and turns "on the same page" into pointless stalling.

Answer (score 11):

I think something like this would be suitable, although I don't particularly think it's any better that what you proposed:

> These reports also ensure that all stakeholders are well-informed
> about the current status of the project and that their priorities are
> aligned. (Alternatively: "in alignment").

Answer (score 3):

I would use *on the same page* in normally formal situations (work e-mail to an outside group). But if you want the type of overly-formal stuff that often goes on resumes, try [in concordance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20concordance%20with): in agreement with (from Merriam-Webster).

Answer (score 3):

One uses the expression “on the same page” to avoid having to actually specify what that immediately means.  Conversely, then, a more formal expression would require one to actually detail what the agreement is *about* — what we are agreed *on*.

As per the question, then, you would say something like, “Do we all concur that the latest task and the planned tasks for the upcoming week are steps in the right direction?”.  [The OP might like to actually think more carefully about what exactly is in question.]

Something short is presumably preferable.  Thus (e.g.), “Are we all in agreement around/on the plan and priorities?”.

Alternatively, you could talk about the inverse — “Does anyone have any ideas or objections around the direction we are taking?”.  Note that this is more of an invitation for comment, where the other is more of a statement that we are closing now (unless anyone wishes to disrupt that).

Conversely, you could avoid the [putatively] informal expression, without specifying as above… thus saying (e.g.), “Are we all in agreement on all this?”, or [citing use3067860], “Are we all in concordance about/around all this?”.